# ComboBox SelectedValue via Reflection as DependencyProperty

Tags: silverlight, combobox

I need to get the SelectedValue property of a Silverlight 4 ComboBox as a DependencyPproerty via Reflection but I am not sure how to do this.

```
myComboBox.GetType().GetFields()
```

returns DependencyProperties but only four of the ComboBox's properties are returned and SelectedValue is not one of them.

```
myComboBox.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedValue")
```

gets the property but it's a System.Object and not a DependencyObject.

I am ultimately trying to get to the Bindings for the control, which requires a DependencyProperty not an Object.

Edit:

This is happening in a Behavior and I don't know what the control is, I am working with a ComboBox control right now. All I have is a string passed from XAML. In WPF I could use `mySource="{x:Static ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty}"` as the DependencyProperty but Silverlight doesn't have `x:Static` in XAML. So I am trying to convert `mySource="SelectedValue"` to a DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
myComboBox.GetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty);
```

--EDIT--

To get a `DependencyProperty` from any `Control` type, use following code:

```
DependencyProperty property = control.GetType().GetField(propertyName + "Property",
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(control) as DependencyProperty;

BindingExpression bindingExpression = control.GetBindingExpression(property);

// Use bindingExpression.ParentBinding
```

--EDIT 2--

Following code works for me in a `Silverlight 4 Application`:

```
Control control = new ComboBox();
String propertyName = "SelectedValue";

DependencyProperty property = control.GetType().GetField(propertyName + "Property",
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(control) as DependencyProperty;

BindingExpression bindingExpression = control.GetBindingExpression(property); 
// bindingExpression will be null since we just created a `ComboBox`. It does not have any bindings yet.
```

Comment: Actually this is happening in a Behavior and I don't know what the control is, I am working with a ComboBox control right now. All I have is a string passed from XAML. In WPF I could use mySource="{x:Static ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty}" as the DependencyProperty but Silverlight doesn't have x:Static in XAML. So I am trying to convert mySource="SelectedValue" to a DependencyProperty.

Comment: Looks good, the only problem is GetProperty("SelectedValueProperty") returns a null, GetProperty("SelectedValue") returns an object not a DependencyProperty. (GetFields needs "Property" to be appended.)

Comment: Yes been there, if you try GetFields() on a ComboBox you will only get four DP's. SelectedValueProperty is not one of them. Is that the end of GetFields?

Comment: My MVVM is going to set focus based on a Model's Property via an event, RaiseFocus("SomeProperty"). Each control identifies some property as the BoundProperty for instance "SelectedValue". The behavior is getting that BoundProperty, checking if the Binding.Path.Path == "SomeProperty". If it is focus is passed to that control. 

So basically I get a string representing a DependencyProperty, find the Binding for that property and see if it's bound to a particular value. Josh Smith talked about this method for Focus in a WPF MVVM world, I'm trying to Silverlight it. http://bit.ly/ghBlZG

Answer (score 0):

The property is actually titled `SelectedValueProperty` but if you are trying to get the bindings for the control try this...

```
BindingExpression expression = myComboBox.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty);
```

Comment: Yeah, ComboBox.SelectedValue is a DP and that's where I'm trying to go but this is a Behavior, so the user is passing the name of a property in via a string (see the edit above). So I need to convert a string to a DP.